# how to show file on each list view item selection when there are huge items in listview in android

Tags: android, database, listview

i have 1500 records in database,depending upon users selection i put them in a listview.
when user clicks on any of list view's item i want to show 1 file in which 1 image n rest information is there.
the problem here is,
i m not getting how to implement this thing, because if i use database only for storing rest info n pics then the size of database will be huge as 1500 images will b there.and i cant use switch case or if else also for same .
plz plz help me.
thnx in advance.
regards,
sups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it makes a lot of sense to store the images in the database as blobs... I think a better approach would be to store these images on the SD card and save the filename in the DB.
Of course, it all depends on your architecture and if you have a good reason to save the images in the DB (usually taking a lot of expansive space on users' phones) it's a different story.

Comment: yahh..true thnx...wil think about it.